# How to generate a problem set based on number of points?

Tags: exam, probsoln

I know that `probsoln` can generate a random set of *n* problems for exercises, etc. Is there a way to create a set of problems totaling *n* points instead? In other words, if I have a set of problems of different values, is there a command or package that can generate, say, a twenty-point exam?

I didn't see anything about this in the `probsoln` manual, so I'm inferring that it can't do that. One solution I did think of is this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{probsoln}

\begin{document}
    \header{English 213}{Test on clauses}{Fall 2017}


\loadrandomproblems{5}{2_pt_questions.tex}
\loadrandomproblems{2}{5_pt_questions.tex}


\begin{questions}
\foreachproblem{\question[1]\thisproblem\dotfill}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

But that still requires me to specify how many questions of each value I want and make sure the total value of the exam is correct. Is there a way to specify only the total value of the exam and let LaTeX do the rest?

### Edit

It's not clear to me that this would produce good exams, even if it could be done; I mostly want to try it as an experiment and see what the results are.

Comment: Could you provide a complete example with some questions and stuff? I don't have `2_pt_questions.tex` and `5_pt_questions.tex` on my machine.

Comment: It's not possible in `probsoln` as that package only provides a way of storing the problem and its solution. The marks assigned to each problem are dealt with outside of `probsoln` (for example, through using a class that provides a score command).

Comment: You could possibly use [`datatool` instead](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/datatoolexam.shtml) in which case you could additionally have a field that stores the score, but even that would be tricky within TeX.